# How can I edit a Cell in JavaFX with IntegerProperty?

Tags: java, javafx

I made an Editable Table. For Columns with String Property ist goes:

```
col_age.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    col_age.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent event) {
            String a = event.getNewValue().toString();
            int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
            ((Persona)event.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    event.getTablePosition().getRow()
            )).setAge(i);
        }
    });
```

Now I want to make the column age editable. But age is an Integer. So I tried this:

```
col_age.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    col_age.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent event) {
            String a = event.getNewValue().toString();
            int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
            ((Persona)event.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    event.getTablePosition().getRow()
            )).setAge(i);
        }
    });
```

But I get the following error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: a) you need to use the textFieldTableCell with a converter, see the api doc b) if you are still stuck, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem (could well be that your table isn't setup as expected) c) unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` only works for `TableColumn`s with `String` as second type parameter, i.e. the `cellValueFactory` needs to return `ObservableValue<String>`. `IntegerProperty` implements `ObservableValue<Number>`. The problem is the result of the cell trying to cast the item to `String`.

You need to specify a `StringConverter` for any column item type other than `String`:

```
col_age.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Number>() {

    @Override
    public String toString(Number value) {
        return value == null ? "" : value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Number fromString(String value) {
        return (value == null) ? null : Integer.parseInt(value);
    }

}));
```

This way you should get a `Number` for the `newValue` property of the event:

```
col_age.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<CellEditEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(CellEditEvent event) {
        Number a = (Number) event.getNewValue();
        ((Persona)event.getTableView().getItems().get(
                event.getTablePosition().getRow()
        )).setAge(a.intValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot. Now I have problems with the Method fromString(...).
If edit the age column with a letter, for example a "z", I get a error message. And the problem is  the fromString() method. So I made a try{}catch(){}. But in the catch part I have to return a Number. Do you know how I can set the old value of the cell? Or how to avoid the error message otherwise?